# How to set the correct timezone to get a isoformat datetime string in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to assign to a variable the current datetime string in isoformat like the following:

```
  2018-09-27T16:19:16+02:00
```

What I'm doing is:

```
  import datetime
  ....

  print(datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc, microsecond=0).isoformat())
```

But this is going to print the string with utc tz:

```
2018-09-28T07:05:35+00:00
```

Not clear yet to me what's the clean way I should change tzinfo param to set wanted tz to UTC+02:00 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`utcnow()` already gives you the the time at `+00:00`, if you'd like to recieve the time at a specific timezone, you should provide the timezone as an argument to `now([tz])`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.now(tz = dt.timezone(offset = dt.timedelta(hours = 2))).replace(microsecond = 0).isoformat()
'2018-09-28T09:20:19+02:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the part : tz=dt.timezone(offset=dt.timedelta(hours=2))